# API User for Online Forms

Tags: rest-api, api

If I were to use the REST API to log Cases in Salesforce is there any best practice to follow?

Specifically should I set up a User specifically for API submitted requests or should I simply use a normal user and change owner etc?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

My best practice is to always use a special User seat dedicated to each API client.

Why?

1. You get traceability to the running user (the API user) in field history, `createdBy`, `lastmodifiedBy`
2. You can apply a Profile to the user to limit access
3. You get the opportunity to override/adapt validation rules and other logic where it is important to distinguish between the API user and normal UI users (if such distinction becomes important)

Comment: Your first sentence seems confused?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - nothing like some misplaced punctuation; fixed. Tx

Comment: I am still a little unsure why the word `seat` is in there. Is that a common term?

Comment: @AdrianLarson.  Yep.  See. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-seat_license

Comment: But isn't that user almost...seatless? No single person sits behind it?

Comment: @AdrianLarson. Lol.    You still are paying for the seat license even if user is headless or other body part-less.  :-)